# Entity Framework Core 6 - trim all returned strings by command interception

Tags: string, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, interceptor, trim

When I was working with EF (System.Data.Entity) I successfully used an interceptor to automatically trim all existing strings in the database. 
The *IDbCommandTreeInterceptor* is described in this post: [EF6.1–Workaround Trailing Blanks Issue in String Joins](https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/).

```
    public class StringTrimmerInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
            {
                var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
                if (queryCommand != null)
                {
                    var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new StringTrimmerQueryVisitor());
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                        queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace,
                        newQuery);
                }
            }
        }

        private class StringTrimmerQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
        {
            private static readonly string[] _typesToTrim = { "nvarchar", "varchar", "char", "nchar" };

            public override DbExpression Visit(DbNewInstanceExpression expression)
            {
                var arguments = expression.Arguments.Select(a =>
                {
                    var propertyArg = a as DbPropertyExpression;
                    if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))
                        return EdmFunctions.Trim(a);

                    return a;
                });

                return DbExpressionBuilder.New(expression.ResultType, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need some help to implement the same functionality by **EntityFrameworkCore** *DbCommandInterceptor*.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to found the solution by myself.
First I implemented the abstract class **DbDataReader** in the following way:

```
    public class TrimStringsDataReader : DbDataReader
    {
        private readonly DbDataReader _innerReader;

        public TrimStringsDataReader(DbDataReader innerReader)
        {
            _innerReader = innerReader;
        }

        public override string GetString(int ordinal)
        {
            var value = _innerReader.GetString(ordinal);
    #pragma warning disable CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
            return value?.Trim();
    #pragma warning restore CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
        }

        public override object GetValue(int ordinal)
        {
            var value = _innerReader.GetValue(ordinal);
            if (value is string stringValue)
                value = stringValue.Trim();
            return value;
        }

        public override object this[int ordinal] => _innerReader[ordinal];

        public override object this[string name] => _innerReader[name];

        public override int Depth => _innerReader.Depth;

        public override int FieldCount => _innerReader.FieldCount;

        public override bool HasRows => _innerReader.HasRows;

        public override bool IsClosed => _innerReader.IsClosed;

        public override int RecordsAffected => _innerReader.RecordsAffected;

        public override bool GetBoolean(int ordinal) => _innerReader.GetBoolean(ordinal);
        // And so on all the other methods
    }
```

Then I overrode the **DbCommandInterceptor** class:

```
    public class TrimStringsInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public override DbDataReader ReaderExecuted(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandExecutedEventData eventData,
            DbDataReader result)
        {
            result = new TrimStringsDataReader(result);
            return base.ReaderExecuted(command, eventData, result);
        }

        public override ValueTask<DbDataReader> ReaderExecutedAsync(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandExecutedEventData eventData,
            DbDataReader result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            result = new TrimStringsDataReader(result);
            return base.ReaderExecutedAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

In this way EF Core instantiate the DbDataReader concrete class (it depends on the Driver, i.e. in case of SqlServer is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader) that is passed to the ReaderExecuted/Async, so I can use the real reader "decorated" with my trim string behaviour.